# Special Relativity and Accelerated Reference Frames

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, reference-frames, resource-recommendations, acceleration

I am looking for a good reference on how to treat accelerating reference frames in special relativity, particularly with respect to accelerating linear motion and circular motion. Are there any that you all would particularly recommend?

Comment: Add the resources recommend tag and check the list of related answers on the right hand side of this page

Comment: The chapter titled "Accelerated Observers" from the MTW would be the perfect source IMO.

Answer (score 3):

The following are some free resources:

- [Space, Time and Coordinates in a Rotating World](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/315444/Dieks-04SpaceTimeandCoordinatesinaRotatingWorld.pdf?sequence=1) by **Dieks** is a good short review article on rotation in relativity. The mathematical level is pretty basic, and the only real prerequisite is familiarity with special relativity.
- [The Rich Structure of Minkowski Space](https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.4345) by **Giulini** has a detailed and rigorous discussion of the Herglotz-Noether theorem.
- [Special Relativity](http://www.lightandmatter.com/sr/) by **Crowell** (me) includes ch. 8 on rotation, and section 9.5 covering congruences, expansion, rigidity, a treatment of the Herglotz-Noether theorem in 1+1 dimensions, and a discussion of the Bell spaceship paradox. This is aimed at people who have completed a freshman physics survey.
- **Semay**, "[Observer with a constant proper acceleration](http://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0601179)," is a nice review article.
- Wikipedia has an article on [Rindler coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates).

Here are some non-free references:

- The classic presentation of the Bell spaceship paradox is "How to teach special relativity," in **J.S. Bell**, "Speakable and unspeakable in quantum mechanics." This is unfortunately out of print and extremely expensive. You can find illegal PDFs online.
- **Grøn**, Relativistic description of a rotating disk, Am. J. Phys. 43 869 (1975)
- R**izzi and Ruggiero**, eds., Relativity in Rotating Frames: Relativistic Physics in Rotating Reference Frames